# Using a data frame from the first for loop in second for loop (R)

Tags: r, for-loop

Due to imbalances in characteristics between my training and validation sets, I am trying to build prediction models in 100 training sets selected using different set.seeds, and then, I'm trying to calculate the average of the performance statistics from the 100 prediction models in 100 validation sets.

I have figured out how to create 100 data frames with different set.seeds used for randomly assigning individuals (i.e rows) into training and validation sets using "for loop." An example of this code follows...

## Use new set.seed to resample 80% training and 20% validation sets in 100 dataframes

```
for(i in 1:100){  
    set.seed(i)
    id <- sample(seq(1, 2), size = nrow(dataframe), replace = TRUE, prob = c(.8, .2))
    assign(paste0("train", i), dataframe[id == 1,])
    assign(paste0("valid", i), dataframe[id == 2,])
}
```

This creates data frames labelled "train1, train2,...train100" and "valid1, valid2,...valid100." These data frames have slight differences in the number of individuals included. I now would like to develop 100 prediction models using the 100 training sets that I created. In order to develop those models, I need to build 100 matrices of variables for each training set (i.e. train data frame). I have included a simple (but incorrect) example of what I am trying to do:

```
for(i in 1:100){  

#Matrix 1: age (spline with 1 knot) + sex + individual characteristics
mod1_X=as.formula(~(bs(AGE, df=3) + SEX + CHF + COPD + DEMENTIA)

assign(paste0("xmat",i), model.matrix(mod1_X,train[i]))
}
```

However, the code above does not work (I do not get xmat1, xmat2...xmat100) because I cannot figure out how to specify train[i]. For example, I want to use data frame train1 to create xmat1, but the code above is not specifying train1 in model.matrix(). Does anyone know how I could specify train[i] in this second "for loop", or is anyone aware of a better method than "for loop" for creating and testing models in multiple training/validation sets (e.g. bootstrapping)?

Comment: Try changing `train[i]` to `get(paste0("train", i))`

Comment: Thank you! That works. I had been trying to use `assign(paste0("train",i))`, and that had not been working. Also, I decided to run 1 long for loop for my entire analysis and only assign loop-specific names to the lists with my performance statistics. It takes much longer to run, and you cannot run sections of code. However, this method cuts down on the number of data frames, matrices, and lists in my environment.